# Cocos3D integration in UIViewController crashing

Tags: ios6, cocos3d

Hi I am trying to integrate Cocos3D into my current project.

I can successfully run it when i set UIViewControllerCOCOS containing Cocos3D code (Listed below) in App Delegate as root of UINavigationController.

But if i use some other viewController say OtherVC and push UIViewControllerCOCOS on navigationController then it crashes on

```
_viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; //APPLICATION CRASH HERE SAYING -[CCDirectorDisplayLink setSupportedInterfaceOrientations:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146ab0b0. Where 
_viewController is CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController* _viewController;
```

I have used Cocos3D hello world code.

//UIViewControllerCOCOS.m

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self setupCocos3D];
}

-(void)setupCocos3D{

CCTexture2D.defaultAlphaPixelFormat = kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888;

// Establish the view controller and CCDirector (in cocos2d 2.x, these are one and the same)
[self establishDirectorController];

[self.view addSubview:_viewController.view];

// ******** START OF COCOS3D SETUP CODE... ********

// Create the customized CC3Layer that supports 3D rendering.
cc3Layer = [Nabru_cocos3dLayer layerWithController: _viewController];

// Create the customized 3D scene and attach it to the layer.
// Could also just create this inside the customer layer.
cc3Layer.cc3Scene = [Nabru_cocos3dScene scene];

// Assign to a generic variable so we can uncomment options below to play with the capabilities
CC3ControllableLayer* mainLayer = cc3Layer;

_viewController.controlledNode = mainLayer;

// Run the layer in the director
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
[scene addChild: mainLayer];
[CCDirector.sharedDirector runWithScene: scene];
}

-(void) establishDirectorController {

_viewController = CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController.sharedDirector;
_viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; //APPLICATION CRASH HERE SAYING -[CCDirectorDisplayLink setSupportedInterfaceOrientations:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146ab0b0. If i comment out this line then it crash second line below it. 

_viewController.viewShouldUseStencilBuffer = NO;        // Set to YES if using shadow volumes
_viewController.viewPixelSamples = 1;                   // Set to 4 for antialiasing multisampling
_viewController.animationInterval = (1.0f / kAnimationFrameRate);
_viewController.displayStats = YES;
[_viewController enableRetinaDisplay: YES];
}
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: is there any error log?

Comment: As i mentioned in my question like "_viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; //APPLICATION CRASH HERE SAYING -[CCDirectorDisplayLink setSupportedInterfaceOrientations:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146ab0b0. If i comment out this line then it crash second line below it."